# Angular Material 'Mat select closing Issue in Internet explorer' on select of option inside

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, angular-material, angular8

any idea on closing the Angular material 'mat-select' in Internet explorer after selecting the value check 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean when you click outside the mat-select it is not closing? I tested the sample with the IE 11 browser and it worked fine on my side. See here: https://imgur.com/a/2w94iDY Which version of the IE browser you are using for the test? If possible then try to provide any sample or demo to test the issue.

Comment: IE 11 and 10 We have working with

Comment: Can you please try to provide any sample code? That can produce the issue. Our test code is working correctly. so if you share any sample then it can help us to produce the issue.

Comment: Add this code in polyfills.ts and check if(!Element.prototype.matches) {
 Element.prototype.matches = (<any>Element.prototype).msMatchesSelector;
}

Comment: I have the same IE11 issue when the page is embedded inside a Dynamics CRM dashboard. The same webresource opened in new windows works fine.